# NAMES column of "docker ps" output

Tags: docker, docker-container

Below is the docker file:

```
FROM golang:1.14.10

MAINTAINER xyz

ENV SOURCES /product-api

COPY . ${SOURCES}

WORKDIR /product-api

RUN make swagger

ENTRYPOINT product-api
```

---

After running the below commands:

`$ docker build -t cloud-native-product-api:1.0.0`

`$ docker run -it -p 8080:8080 cloud-native-product-api:1.0.0`

---

`docker ps` gives below output:

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                            COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
9aa144b7873c        cloud-native-product-api:1.0.0   "/bin/sh -c product-…"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes        0.0.0.0:9090->9090/tcp   trusting_matsumoto
```

---

Where does value `trusting_matsumoto` derive from in `NAMES` column?

Comment: It is a random generated value. If you want/need specific value for the name, please use "--name" parameter during the "docker run" command.

Comment: @DeepakChampatiray How to override that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you specify a name for the container, docker assigns a random one.

You can specify a container name by using the `--name` argument:

```
$ docker run --rm -it --name my_alpine_container alpine
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#container-identification)

> If you do not assign a container name with the `--name` option, then the daemon generates a random string name for you. Defining a name can be a handy way to add meaning to a container. If you specify a name, you can use it when referencing the container within a Docker network. This works for both background and foreground Docker containers.